# LiveUSB creator that works on 14.04

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb, usb-drive, unetbootin

I want to create another LiveUSB of Lubuntu 15.10 or higher with a LiveUSB creator on a Lubuntu 14.04 LiveUSB. Last time I checked, 14.04-14.10 doesn't work AT ALL. It creates the disk and the disk fails to boot on any Windows computer even with 32-bit image.

The Solution needs to successfully create a LiveUSB to a different version and be able to make other LiveUSBs from unetbootin. The Solution also needs to produce a disk with Persistence as an end-result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `gnome-disks` tool to create a live usb of any distribution and it works for me every time (startup-disk-creator does not), though it is a bit unclear it can do that.

If it is not preinstalled in `lubuntu` run

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disks
```

Now open it and choose your USB drive on the left, now click the small cog icon in the `volumes` section

[image]

Choose `restore partition image` from the list.

Now give this the `.iso` file and choose `start restoring`, it will install it on your USB stick.

[image]

Comment: This one because of the implication we don't read questions, that will annoy people fast. The other was just because it was a duplicate, I myself don't downvote the duplicates but many do it seems. Don't worrie about it, as long as you get the answer you want, it is not important. If this answer works for you, please accept it with the check mark on the left, if not, please say why, so I can adjust it.

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns something, but I can't remember what. I'll come back with the output because I can't Ctrl+Shift+C copy it. Thanks for the explanation by the way, I'm new to asking here.